# Convert comma separated list to serialized array to import as post meta

Tags: custom-post-types, import

I have a very site WordPress site that was custom built with custom tables for a membership system.  I'm updating the site and trying to figure out how to re-upload the new fields as serialized data.

For instance a "member" CPT has a custom field called "hours_of_operation".   The data in that field is "Morning/Daytime".  but I would like to get it to something like `a:2{{i:0;s:7:"Morning";i:1;s:7:"Daytime";}`.

Other data is stored in other fashions, but I'm trying to piece a few together.

Comment: How are you importing the data? How do you want to do this conversion? With PHP? Or manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this conversion in PHP, as part of whatever import process, then you can just convert the comma-separated values into an array with `explode()`, and then use `update_post_meta()`, which will automatically serialise the value for you:

```
$value = 'Morning,Daytime';
$array = explode( ',', $value );

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hours_of_operation', $array );
```

Use `trim()` if your comma separated values include, or could include, spaces:

```
$value = 'Morning, Daytime';
$array = explode( ',', $value );
$array = array_map( 'trim', $array );

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hours_of_operation', $array );
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to serialise the value yuorself in PHP, you can use `serialize()` to convert the array to a serialised string.

```
$value      = 'Morning,Daytime';
$array      = explode( ',', $value );
$serialized = serialize( $array );
```